# Python packages.'import sys' vs 'from sys import argv'

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm trying to use 'argv' into my python script.
For this i'm using following code:

```
from sys import argv
script, file_name = argv
print(file_name)
```

python3 e.py e.txt
This code works fine.

But when I use:

```
import sys
```

and try to use 'argv', I get error:

> 'NameError: name 'argv' is not defined '.

I don't understand this as by importing 'sys' full module becomes usable into my code.

Can you explain why does this happen? How to packages work?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you "trying to use `argv`"?  Have you tried `import sys; script, file_name = sys.argv`?

Comment: You would have to do a `from sys import *`, or keep your current `import sys` and use `sys.argv`. I wouldn't recommend the first one as it can lead to serious *namespace polution* (or whatever it is called in Python).

Comment: `import sys; print(len(dir(sys)))` is 83.  That's the last module I'd want to `import *` on.  Please don't suggest that.

Comment: Just replace script, `file_name = argv` with `script, file_name = sys.argv` and it will work. You need to fully reference.

Answer (score 1):

Import sys does not give you direct access to any of the names inside sys itself
To access those you need to prefix them with sys:

```
sys.argv
sys.exit()
```

If you want use argv instead sys.argv try

```
from sys import *
```

Answer (score -3):

**@Aman**, have a look at the following 2 code examples.

> Check this beautiful https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports for more information about **imports**.

sys_file_name.py »

> import sys

```
import sys

script, file_name = sys.argv;

print(script, file_name);
```

Output »

```
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\SysFileName>python sys_file_name.py  file1.txt
sys_file_name.py file1.txt
```

sys_file_name2.py »

> from sys import argv

```
from sys import argv

script, file_name = argv;

print(script, file_name);
```

Output »

```
E:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\SysFileName>python sys_file_name2.py file2.txt
sys_file_name2.py file2.txt
```

Comment: This is formatted really badly. Also you don't need to put semicolons all over Python code.